# How to submit a form with a captcha?

Tags: ruby, forms, submit, captcha

I'm trying to download my own files from [uptobox.com](http://uptobox.com) using Ruby. But I got stuck when the captcha was displayed (which is just random numbers in a `span` html-tag generated with some Javascript). I think there may also be some problems with the download-timer. On page3 it says `"wrong captcha"`

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page1 = agent.get("http://uptobox.com/pzlw7p8d651h")
form_page1 = page1.forms.first

page2 = form_page1.submit(form_page1.button_with(:name => "method_free"))
form_page2 = page2.form_with(:name => "F1")
captcha = page2.parser.search("td[@align='right']/div").inner_text
form_page2.field_with(:name => "code").value = captcha

p form_page2

// 60s has to pass before the button is enabled. the prog waits 70s
timeToWait = (page2.parser.search("*[id='countdown_str']/span").text).to_i + 10
p Time.now.getutc
sleep(timeToWait)  
p Time.now.getutc

button = form_page2.button_with(:value => "Create Download Link")
page3 = agent.submit(form_page2,button)

p page3.content
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your captcha will always be incorrect if you use `...search("td[@align='right']/div").inner_text`. Because the page uses `padding-left` to change the sequence of characters in captcha.

To get it right, you need to pull the values of `padding-left` in ascending order, then use the actual inner_text.

e.g.

```
<span style="position:absolute;padding-left:28px;padding-top:4px;">4</span> #=> 2nd
<span style="position:absolute;padding-left:9px;padding-top:7px;">3</span> #=> 1st
<span style="position:absolute;padding-left:44px;padding-top:6px;">9</span> #=> 3rd
<span style="position:absolute;padding-left:62px;padding-top:3px;">7</span> #=> 4th
```

Comment: thx alot, then i just have to figure how to put dem in the correct order

Comment: That is correct. Your can accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: do you now if it is possible to access the style code? something like: span.style["padding-left"]

Comment: it works with: p (page2.parser.search("td[@align='right']/div/span[1]").attr('style').value).split(";")[1].split(":")[1][0..-3] is there a better solution?